# Excel: Return Column Name for column with largest value

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns (W:Y) each with their own name (i.e. Fee Structure, Insurance, Spelling/Grammar)

[image: Example]

I want to write a formula that references the name of the column that has the largest value.  I tried using MAX with INDEX and MATCH but I have been unsuccessful. This is the formula I attempted:

```
=index(W1:Y1, match(max(W:Y),W:Y,0))
```

What do I need to do to fix this formula?

Comment: what result do you expect? question is not exact.
Do you want the name of the column with maximum value for each row (so, a 4th column with results none/none/none/.../Insurance/Insurance), or do you want the name of the column with overall max value, so "Insurance" because there exists the value 8.0 as max value once in full table?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want the name of the column with the overall max value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper-row that calculates the per-column max value with "MAX" formula (GREEN)
Then, add a second helper row with the column indexes for your data columns (BLUE)

with HLOOKUP, determine the column index of the column with max-value
and finally, unse INDEX to get the value of your header column with the max value

[image]

Formulas for green cells (assuming picture showing A:E) are

```
=MAX(B2:B10)
=MAX(C2:C10)
=MAX(D2:D10)
```

Blue cells are fixed-values

Calculated value (COL-Index) / consider the "FALSE", because values are not ordered - we need an exact match!

```
=HLOOKUP(MAX(B11:D11);B11:D12;2;FALSE)
```

and finally, the resulting INDEX:

```
=INDEX(B1:D1;1;E13)
```

Comment: and of course, you could set intermediate columns to "invisible"... - there is also some potential for improvements, e.g. get rid of E13 and combine it with E14...

Comment: For those working with German version of MS Excel - use WVERWEIS instead of HLOOKUP (for whatever reason did microsoft introduce translation into excel formulas?)

Comment: As soon as you added the row with green background (MAX value per column), you can determine the position of max value within the green row (not within a matrix, just within a row!) using the MATCH function. You could e.g. write in E11: ´=INDEX(B1:D1;1;MATCH(MAX(B11:D11);B11:D11;0))` (in German version, use VERGLEICH instead of MATCH)

Comment: Thank you so much! The helper row pushed me to think differently about how to solve this problem. I appreciate your assistance!